# How improve performance Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6

How do I improve the performance of Entity Framework with getting a million records?

Table items have a million records and relationship with another table.
When making a `linq` query, it takes more than 10 seconds to get the data

```
items(id int identity(1,1) primary key ,itemName nvarchar(max),code nvarchar(100),
branchId int foreign key,categoryId int foreign key)

branch(id int primary key,title nvarchar(max))
category(id int primary key,title nvarchar(max), parentId int self relationship)
```

Comment: Please post table structure, data set and your critical query

Comment: 10 seconds to get a million records. that's 100,000 records per second. Why do you think it's slow? And why on earth do you want to get all 1,000,000 records at once?

Comment: retail application and user choose item from all items

Comment: You don't need to fetch them all at once. Take a look at paging or if you need something more sophisticated [Lucene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Lucene).